# How to setup Xiaomi AX6000 as an access point?

Tags: router, wireless-access-point

My current network already has a powerful router so I'd like the AX6000 to only act as an access point. How do I set it up as an access point?

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to do, but right now the firmware is only available in Chinese.

Before you set it up, make sure you connect the AX6000 to your network using either port 1 or port 2 (which one doesn't matter since they're adaptive). Then connect the power and connect to it either wirelessly or using an ethernet cable.

Once connected you'd be redirected to miwifi.com where you should do the following:

1. Click the big blue button, probably accepting terms.
   [image: Big blue button]
2. Click on the blue link at the bottom (probably means "advanced setup").
   [image: Blue link at bottom]
3. Select the last option, which is "Wired Repeater" (or more commonly access point).
   [image: Last option]
4. Enter the Wi-Fi details you want it to use and then wait for it to restart and then connect the the mentioned IP address it received from your DHCP server. The Wi-Fi password became the admin password and can be changed later.
   [image: IP address of AX6000]

It's also possible to set it up using the phone app, but I haven't tried that.